# Drawing Bitmaps onto Canvas overlapping

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I have been working this problem out for a week now and I know its something so silly. When I run my app on a phone or emulator the bitmaps that are being drawn are overlapping. Sorry for my grammar and my question but here the code and a screen shot of the emulator.

```
//How I am rendering / drawing the bitmaps
public void render() {

    if (gameHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
        gameCanvas = gameHolder.lockCanvas();
        gameCanvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        int w = gameCanvas.getWidth();
        int h = gameCanvas.getHeight();

        Log.i("measure", w + " | " + h);

        gameCanvas.drawBitmap(loadInBitmaps(1), (w / 2), h / 2, gamePaint);
        gameCanvas.drawBitmap(loadInBitmaps(2), (w / 2) + 32, h / 2, gamePaint);

        gameHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(gameCanvas);
    }
}


//How I am loading in the bitmaps
public Bitmap loadInBitmaps(int number) {

    Bitmap loadedBitmap = null;

    if (number == 0) loadedBitmap = null;
    //UI Bitmaps
    if (number == 1)
        loadedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.northbutton);
    if (number == 2)
        loadedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.southbutton);

    return loadedBitmap;
}
```

[Emulator Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNSPV.jpg)

Comment: I would like to also add I am using 32 x 32 sprites.

Comment: Are the drawables saved in a specific res folder ?(hdpi/xhdpi .. ?). Can you print what are the value of loadedBitmap.getWidth() is right after you instantiate it  ?

Comment: @Gauthier I have the images just saved in the default drawable folder, also I feel like an idiot for not checking the size of the bit maps. The bitmaps are returning 48 x 48. Could you explain why they are scaling up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you put your drawables in the default *drawable* directory, Android assumes that your Bitmap needs to be scaled from the default mdpi size. 
Put your drawables in *drawable-nodpi* if you want to disable resource scaling.

Comment: Thank you so much @Gauthier